# How do I 301 redirect specific pages to remove part of the URL?

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-301

Every URL that begins with:

```
https://example.com/usa/example-1/
```

I want to redirect to a URL with `example-1` changed to `example-2`:

```
https://example.com/usa/example-2/
```

for example, this URL:

```
https://example.com/usa/example-1/state/city/
```

to be redirected to:

```
https://example.com/usa/example-2/state/city/
```

etc.

Can you help? I always have a hard time using `.htaccess` so I prefer to ask before testing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like the following at the *top* of your `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteRule ^(usa)/example-1/(.*) /$1/example-2/$2 [R=301,L]
```